# Issue parsing JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm getting a JSON object (I think) back from my `AJAX` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'testing.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                code: code_got,
            },
            success: function(data) {
              var list_data = data;
              console.log(list_data);//this is the object shown below
        var list_name = list_data['data']['name'];
        console.log(list_name);//this throws an error that `name` is undefined
            }
          });
});
```

The response looks like this:

```
 {
  "total" : 5,
  "data" : [
    {
      "id" : "312464ee1e",
      "stats" : {
        "members" : 58,
      },
      "web_id" : 11966492,
      "name" : "List 1"
    },
    {
      "id" : "312464ee1e",
      "stats" : {
        "members" : 123,
      },
      "web_id" : 1196649,
      "name" : "List 2"
    },

  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get (first off) the first list name. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var list_data = data;
console.log(list_data);//this is the object shown above
var list_name = list_data['data']['name']; //this throw an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
```

Second, I want to do an `each` to get all of the `name` items from the data, but I can't get to this until I figure out the JSON structure.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is data an object or a string?

Comment: `var list_data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: I'm guessing that's the problem, but I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi Thanks. That was the step I was missing. Now the question is how to do my `each` since I can't do `list_data['data'][0]['name'];` what do I put in place of the number?

Comment: I'll generate an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must parse it as json and then loop through it

```
success: function(data) {
    var lists = JSON.parse(data);
    var dataset = list['data'];
    for(var i=0; i< dataset.length; i++)
        console.log(dataset[i]['name']);
}
```

Or you can loop through it using `$.each`:

```
$.each(dataset, function(index, d){
    console.log(d.name);
});
```

Also instead of using `JSON.parse()` you can set the `dataType` parameter of `ajax` as `'json'` if you know that the returned data is json.

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    dataType: 'json',
    ....
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl yes I said that either, Am I wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an object property on an array `list_data['data']`:

you want a property of an object *within* that array

Try

```
var list_name = list_data['data'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: Got it...how do I use this in an `each` since I can't have the `[0]` position in there?

Comment: Within `each` you will have instance of each object ...`$.each(list_data['data'], function(index, obj){ console.log(obj.name);})`

Comment: also set `dataType:'json'` in ajax options

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the position within the JSON to the end.

```
var list_name = list_data['data'][0]['name']
```

Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) on JSON from W3Schools

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, "data" is an array. (simple mistake)
The following will log out the value of name. "List 1"

```
console.log(list_data.data[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your data and use `$.each` function:

For example:

```
      success: function(data){
           var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(parsed_data, function(index, value){
                 console.log(jndex, value);
             });
     }
```